# Returning data from asynchronous function through callback comes as undefined

Tags: javascript, html, api, asynchronous

The function gets the data from URL and then passes it to another function where the listing is done dynamically based on users in the list of URL. I tried callback but I am getting the following error `service.js:9 Uncaught TypeError: callback is not a function`

This is the function in one js file:

```
function GetData(callback, passdata) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users',
        success: function (response) {
            debugger;
            console.log(response);
            return callback(response, passdata);
        }
    });
 }
```

This is the function in another js file (wherein I want to list the data from the URL):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

        var getData = GetData();
        var $data = $('#dataDisplay');

        function listData(response, passdata) {
            var data = response;
            var passeddata = passdata;

            $.each(data, function (i, users) {
                $data.append('<li>' + '<span>' + users.name + '</span>' + '<br> <span>' + users.email + '</span>' + ' </li>');
            });

            //adds li dynamically 
            $("li").append('<i class="material-icons delete">' + "delete" + '</i>');
            $("li").append('<i class="material-icons edit">' + "edit" + '</i>');

    }
});
```

Comment: @KrishnaPrashatt I tried that callback but dont seem to know what is going wrong.

Comment: Callback is a generic name for the functions which are supposed to get executed after the response of an asynchronous call. In your case you are calling the function `callback(response, passdata)` but there is no function definition for the same

Comment: How do I add the function definition? @KrishnaPrashatt

Comment: You have to add a function definition for callback(response, passdata). This will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this worked

```js
function GetData(callback) {
  debugger;
  $.ajax({
   type: 'GET',
   url: ' http://localhost:3000/users',
   success: function (response) {
    console.log(response);
    callback(response);
   }
  });
 }
```

In another js file call the function back and pass the response parameter for that is where the array of the API was saved.

```js
GetData(function (response) {
        debugger;
        var data = response;
        var $data = $('#dataDisplay');
        $.each(data, function (i, users) {
            $data.append('<li>' + '<span class="table .table-striped .table-hover">' + users.first_name + '</span>' + ' <span class="table .table-striped .table-hover">' + users.email + '</span>' + ' </li>');
        });
        //adds li dynamically 
        $("li").append('<i class="material-icons delete ">' + "delete" + '</i>');
        $("li").append('<i class="material-icons edit ">' + "edit" + '</i>');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use anonymous function in document ready =>

```
GetData(function(result){
// can do further things here..
console.log(result);

}, passdata);
```

this should fix your error.

Answer (score 0):

How can JavaScript know that `listData` is the callback function if you don't specify it?

You just declared the `listData` function, but you aren't using it anywhere. There is not any sort of magic that will do it for you :)

Just change

```
var getData = GetData();
```

To

```
var getData = GetData(listData, 'something');
```